# Can we compare clusters with C-Index average?

Tags: data-mining, clustered-index, knime

I use K-Means algorithm to create clusters. As you know K-means algorithm needs cluster count as parameter. I try cluster counts as starting two from eight and calculate all C-Index of clusters in every looping then get the avegare of these C-Indexes. Then compare C-Index avegares and choose the minimum C-Index average as best quality cluster count. Is that true way for detecting cluster count?

Answer (score 1):

There is no one correct way to detect cluster count. See following [google search](https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=determining%20cluster%20number), this is still an active research area. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determining_the_number_of_clusters_in_a_data_set) articles says that:

> The correct choice of k is often ambiguous, with interpretations depending on the shape and scale of the distribution of points in a data set and the desired clustering resolution of the user.

Only you can determine if using c-index in this way is a good way to determine cluster numbers in your domain. See another question of using [c-index in clustering](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2631/can-someone-explain-the-c-index-in-the-context-of-hierarchical-clustering).